# Can some one explain logging device placement in tensorflow tutorial ?

Tags: tensorflow

[Link for the tf tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/using_gpu)

```
# Creates a graph.
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
  a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
  b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
  c = tf.matmul(a, b)
# Creates a session with log_device_placement set to True.
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
# Runs the op.
print sess.run(c)
```

In above example cpu:0 has assigned to the execution process. **With the log_device_placement** true. So this is solution for the above code that the have mentioned

```
Device mapping:
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0 -> device: 0, name: Tesla K40c, pci bus
id: 0000:05:00.0
b: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
a: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
MatMul: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
[[ 22.  28.]
 [ 49.  64.]]
```

Now here place holders a, b and the matmul operation c which runs inside a session is inside the device log cpu:o but in the log device description ***why only MatMul has been executed in gpu:0 ?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems like a bug in the documentation, the MatMul operation will be placed on CPU in this case.

Indeed, running the code sample does show this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
# Creates a graph.
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
  a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3],  name='a')
  b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
  c = tf.matmul(a, b)
# Creates a session with log_device_placement set to True.
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
# Runs the op.
print sess.run(c)

# And to prove that GPUs exist and can be used
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
  d = tf.random_normal([])
print sess.run(d)
```

Will show the following placements:

```
MatMul: (MatMul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
b: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
a: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
random_normal/RandomStandardNormal: (RandomStandardNormal): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
```

I think the documentation bug is that the `c = tf.matmul(a, b)` statement was supposed to be outside the `with tf.device('/cpu:0')` scope.

Comment: Oh I got it. So if we implement something outside of the scope it will run by default device that is the GPU. Is my understanding is correct ?

Comment: Yes. (Technically, there is no _default device_ - The runtime is free to choose a device based on the set of devices available, the operation being conducted and any other information it has)